# loading bokehJS in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am having a strange behavior with bokeh library.

So apparently, I am trying to create some beautiful plots with bokeh. When I try to load the bokeh in JupyterLab, I get constant, "Loading bokehJS..." message but if I try to plot with jupyter (`from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show output_notebook()`), I could plot it. It looks like lab has some issues? or am I not using lab properly?

comparative screenshot attached. Dark (`JupyterLab`), Light(`Jupyter Notebook`)

[image: JuputerLab (Dark) vs Jupyter Notebook(Light) comparision]

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to install the jupyterlab_bokeh extension:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyterlab

Comment: Thanks Luke, Received an installation error. Opened an issue here : https://github.com/bokeh/jupyterlab_bokeh/issues/47